# Problems using the WMI EnableStatic method

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm trying to create a tool that converts the dynamic DHCP-provided IPv4 address, gateway and dns-settings into static configuration. I've tried to use WMI to solve this puzzle, but I have a problem I can't figure out.

The application completes, DNS and Gateway is configured, but the `EnableStatic` method (to set the IP address and subnet) has been unsuccesful which means that the IP is still received from DHCP (with greyed out fields) even though the default gateway has been set. How do I fix this?

The ReturnValue from EnableStatic is 70 (Invalid IP address). The weird thing is that the input parameters are the same that I extracted from the NIC 2 seconds earlier.

Here is the code (except GUI),  http://pastebin.com/AE3dGhUz:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Management;

namespace Static_NIC_Settings_Creator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection;
        private string[] networkInterfaces;
        private int currentNIC;
        private string[] ipAddress;
        private string[] subnetMask;
        private string[] defaultIPGateway;
        private string[] dnsServerSearchOrder;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            getNICs();
        }

        private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (networkInterfaces.Count() > 0)
            {
                //Get current NIC settings
                if (!getNICSettings())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Retrieving current NIC settings failed.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }
                //Convert to static NIC settings
                if (!setNICStatic())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Setting NIC settings to static failed.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        private void nicSelecter_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentNIC = nicSelecter.SelectedIndex;
        }

        private void getNICs()
        {
            //Get NICS
            ManagementObjectSearcher query = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = 'TRUE'");
            queryCollection = query.Get();
            //Make nic string array
            int i = queryCollection.Count;
            networkInterfaces = new string[i];
            //Fill nic string array
            i = 0;
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection)
            {
                networkInterfaces[i] = (String)mo["Description"];
                i++;
            }
            //Fill dropbox with arraylist-data
            nicSelecter.DataSource = networkInterfaces;
        }

        private Boolean getNICSettings()
        {
            //Get selected NIC
            int i = 0;
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection)
            {
                //Get settings for specific NIC
                if (i == currentNIC)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ipAddress = (String[])mo["IPAddress"];
                        subnetMask = (String[])mo["IPSubnet"];
                        defaultIPGateway = (String[])mo["DefaultIPGateway"];
                        dnsServerSearchOrder = (String[])mo["DNSServerSearchOrder"];
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Critical: Unhandled error");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private Boolean setNICStatic()
        {
            //Get selected NIC
            int i = 0;
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in queryCollection)
            {
                //Get settings for specific NIC
                if (i == currentNIC)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Set static IP and subnet mask
                        ManagementBaseObject setIP;
                        ManagementBaseObject newIP = mo.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");
                        newIP["IPAddress"] = ipAddress;
                        newIP["SubnetMask"] = subnetMask;
                        setIP = mo.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);
                        //Set default gateway
                        ManagementBaseObject setGateway;
                        ManagementBaseObject newGateway = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");
                        newGateway["DefaultIPGateway"] = defaultIPGateway;
                        newGateway["GatewayCostMetric"] = new int[] { 1 };
                        setGateway = mo.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", newGateway, null);
                        //Set dns servers
                        ManagementBaseObject setDNS;
                        ManagementBaseObject newDNS = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
                        newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = dnsServerSearchOrder;
                        setDNS = mo.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDNS, null);

                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Setting NIC settings returned: " + setDNS);
                        return true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Critical: Unhandled error");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            //No NICs
            return false;
        }
    } //End class
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you are inputting [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) addresses as well? Just playing around with PowerShell it seems not to like them. Perhaps you can post actual values that are being inputted whilst debugging, it would help a lot. Also maybe try statically inputting some values like:

```
new string[]{"192.168.0.1"}, new string[] {"255.255.255.255"}
```

Also unless you really, really need C# and a GUI you may want to consider using PowerShell (requirement is it being installed of course) as WMI is really much simpler to manipulate there (sadly you still have that learning curve though).

This is just an example of how to use PowerShell, you can at the very least use it for some testing:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
```

Then get the index of your adapter then run, but replace your index number:

```
$obj = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where {$_.Index -eq 1}
$obj.EnableStatic("192.168.0.1", "255.255.255.0")
```

To get method parameters just run:

```
$obj.EnableStatic
```

It will return:

```
MemberType          : Method
OverloadDefinitions : {System.Management.ManagementBaseObject EnableStatic(System.String[]IPAddress, System.String[] SubnetMask)}
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Management.Automation.PSMethod
Value               : System.Management.ManagementBaseObject EnableStatic(System.String[]IPAddress, System.String[] SubnetMask)
Name                : EnableStatic
IsInstance          : True
```

Comment: This was long overdue. I had given this up a long time ago, but now when I'm practicing on PS, I took the time to test the C# app too. There seems to be something about IP6, so I used `newIP["IPAddress"] = new String[] {ipAddress[0]};` and similar for subnet to get the ipv4 settings only. Multiple ipaddresses isn't likely for it's use anyways. Great catch =)

Comment: The description of the IPAddresses property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394217(v=vs.85).aspx#properties) says: "This property can contain either IPv6 addresses or IPv4 addresses". Now, when you query it, it seems to contain both v4 and v6 addresses, but maybe it only counts when you try to change it (using e.g. EnableStatic(). I have noticed error 70 myself, if you use mixed addresses with EnableStatic().

Answer (score 0):

Another tip for those who might stumble across this on search...

If your current IP address is DHCP assigned, and EnableStatic() is returning 2147944122 or 2147944117 error codes, verify the dhcp service (DHCP Client) in Windows is enabled and started.

I found that switching from one static address to another using EnableStatic() works OK.  But if you have a dynamic address, and the DHCP service is disabled (possibly due to security reasons), then EnableStatic() will not work.

Adding this solution to the internet, in case it saves someone time in the future.